# Is there any way to exclude lines from looping inside of a loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I was writing this code for a password generator in python, but when i execute it, it displays "I generated some random Passwords, Pick the one you like!" each time with each password. Is there a way to exclude this line out of this loop? Please help! here is the code:

```
import random


chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#$1234567890"

while 1:
    password_len  = int(input("Please specify the length of password:"))
    password_count =int(input("How many passwords should i generate?"))
    for x in range(0,password_count):
        password =""
        
        for x in range(0,password_len):
            password_char = random.choice(chars)
            password     = password + password_char
        print ("I generated some random Passwords, Pick the one you like!",password)
```

I want it to look like this:

**Please specify the length of password:**-  *4*.
**How many passwords should i generate?**  -  *2*.
**I generated some random Passwords, Pick the one you like!
j7G@
hjh4**

Comment: Don't put it in the loop? print it once before and print the password inside the loop.

Comment: Outdent it by 4 spaces.

Comment: Unindent the `print` call by 4 spaces so it's no longer in the `for` loop and thus not run each time the loop body is executed.

Comment: @xkcdjerry They still need to print the passwords in the loop, so can't just dedent the same statement

Comment: @Phydeaux good point,but excuse me not editing my comment :(   can't be edited cuz 5 minute rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `print("I generated some random Passwords, Pick the one you like!")` out of the first `for` loop and also, you can add `print(password)` at the end of the first `for` loop, so you can see all the passwords generated.

```
import random


chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#$1234567890"

while 1:
    password_len  = int(input("Please specify the length of password:"))
    password_count =int(input("How many passwords should i generate?"))
    for x in range(0,password_count):
        password =""
        
        for x in range(0,password_len):
            password_char = random.choice(chars)
            password     = password + password_char
        print(password)
    print ("I generated some random Passwords, Pick the one you like!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random


chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#$1234567890"

while 1:

    password_len  = int(input("Please specify the length of password:"))
    password_count =int(input("How many passwords should I generate?"))
    print ("I generated some random Passwords, Pick the one you like!")
    for x in range(0,password_count):
        password =""

        for x in range(0,password_len):
            password_char = random.choice(chars)
            password     = password + password_char
        print(password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `print("I generated some random Passwords, Pick the one you like!")` is put in the loop body which means it is executed with every loop.
To fix,move it outside the loop in front of/behind the `for` according to which you'd like better,just don't forget to keep `print(password)` so you can see the passwords.

(I also fixed the slow string concats. BTW,you can save yourself some time typing—`range(0,a)` is the same as `range(a)`)

```
import random


chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#$1234567890"

while 1:

    password_len  = int(input("Please specify the length of password:"))
    password_count =int(input("How many passwords should I generate?"))
    print ("I generated some random Passwords, Pick the one you like!")
    for x in range(password_count):
        password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(password_len))
        print(password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with few edits that you might want to consider to get the code output as you wanted-

```
import random


chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#$1234567890"

password_len  = int(input("Please specify the length of password: "))
password_count =int(input("How many passwords should i generate? "))

print ("I generated some random Passwords, Pick the one you like!")

for x in range(0,password_count):
    password =""
    
    for x in range(0,password_len):
        password_char = random.choice(chars)
        password     = password + password_char
    print (password)
```

You might also want to change the `range(0, password_count)` and `range(0, password_len)` to simply `range(password_count)` and `range(password_len)` as it is implied that the range will begin with `0` (default value) if no other argument is provided.

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day! I've just started learning python from last week. This helped me so much! Thank you once again!